# MySQL - Quick Access to Relation

Tags: mysql, database

Lets say I'm dealing with a large amount of data (hunderds of thousands, or potentially a million + records).  And lets say there's some relationships I need to access often.  For example:

```
user:
  id
  name
  phone

addresses:
  street
  city
  state
  user_id
  primary (tinyint)
  zip_code
```

Not the greatest example, but lets say I found I always needed to grab the `zip_code` for a User's Primary Address for some calculation purposes.  And this data set has hundreds of thousands of Users and Addresses. Does it make sense to **ALSO** store the `zip_code` on the `User` table so that I don't slow down the queries with a Join for a such a small piece of data?

To me, it seems like this could be problematic because you no longer have normalized data.  However, I was curious if it may be beneficial to increase performance for massive data sets.  And perhaps, you'd keep those 'duplicate' columns in sync with triggers?

Comment: As long as you have suitable indexes, the performance hit of joining with the `addresses` table should be mininal. If you don't want to have to complicate all your queries with this join, you can create a view for it.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the info.  What if the thing I need is two, or three relationships away?  I understand that in the end, I'll just have to do some testing and see how it goes.  But I'm wondering if people commonly solve this problem by 'duplicating' data so that it's closer, or if they just deal with the distant relationships and multiple joins

Comment: Sometimes they do, if the queries that depend on the relationship are very frequent and performance of the joins is a problem. But you should first try to do it the normal way, and only add optimizations if you determine that it's not possible to get the needed performance that way.

Answer (score -2):

If a user can only have a single address then your schema is not normalised. If a user can have zero or one address then there is a strong case for implementing this as a single table, but if a user can have more than one address, you can't have a single zip code attribute in users. I.e. your question is moot.

(BTW not everyone would consider a million + records a "large amount")

Comment: please see the schema i presented.  A user has many addresses.  There is a tinyint which specifies whether it is their primary one.  And per my question, the data which I need to get the most is the zip code of the primary address.  Which is why I'm asking about storing that on the Users table in addition to the Address table